# Open port 80 in CentOS 6.5

Tags: centos, iptables, apache-httpd

I'm trying to open the Port 80 in my CentOS 6.5, on my virtual machine, so I can access the apache from my desktop's browser.

[image]

If you take a look at the screenshot above.... I've added the line before the blue arrow, as is written on http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-iptables-firewall-open-port-80/
Now I do get the apache test page when entering the IP-address in my browser, but still when restarting the iptables, I get a "FAILED" when CentOS tries to apply the new rule.

Does anyone know a solution for this? Or do I need to ignore the failure?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Rather than key the rules in manually you can use `iptables` to add the rules to the appropriate chains and then save them. This will allow you to debug the rules live, confirming they're correct, rather than having to add them to the file like you appear to be doing.

To open port 80 I do this:

```
$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
$ sudo /etc/init.d/iptables save
```

The last command will save the added rules. This is the rule I would use to open up the port for web traffic.

#### Why your rule is causing issues

If you notice the rule you're attempting to use:

```
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

Has a chain called "RH-Firewall-1-INPUT". If you do not have this chain, or a link from the `INPUT` chain to this chain, then this rule will never be reachable. This rule could likely be like this:

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

Or your `INPUT` chain should link to this chain `RH-Firewall-1-INPUT` with a rule like this:

```
$ sudo iptables --list
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    RH-Firewall-1-INPUT  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
....
```

**NOTE:** You can see what chains you have with this command:

```
$ sudo iptables -L| grep Chain
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
...
```

Also the states might need to be modified so that existing connections are allowed as well.

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

Also when you use the `-A` switch you're appending the rule to chain `INPUT`. If there are other rules before it that are blocking and/or interfering with the reaching of this rule, it will never get executed. So you might want to move it to the top by inserting rather than appending, like this:

```
-I INPUT -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

#### Using the GUI

Firewalls can be complicated beasts. So you might want to try the TUI instead (TUI's are GUI's for the terminal).

```
$ sudo system-config-firewall-tui
```

You can then go through the various screens setting up `iptables` rules.

[image: ss #1]

[image: ss #2]

#### References

- [Linux Firewall Tutorial: IPTables Tables, Chains, Rules Fundamentals](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/01/iptables-fundamentals/)

Comment: The last rule deleted all previous rules in my iptables file and added just the one above (sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT). Now I cannot access the apache page from my browser anymore, either.

Comment: @ErikVandeVen - sorry I didn't make that clearer. The other rules that you had would either need to be added in this same manner and saved (at the sam time), or you can go to the file `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` and add them. Your original entries should be in this file, `/etc/sysconfig/iptables.save`.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to restore iptables by copying the iptables.save. But I still wasn't able to add the rule without getting a failure and being able to open the apache test page within my browser, at the same time. I'll take a look at the tutorial whcih riclags has posted, first :)

Comment: Man, i totally didnt get why this answer received any single like yet. Excellent detailed reply. Consider my one like as thousand thanks.

Comment: That firewall GUI is a god-send, never seen that before!

Comment: +1ed. thanks for `system-config-firewall-tui`, @slm

Comment: @slm `-m tcp` is redundant since we alredy have `-p tcp`, isn't it? It seems like it is because when I add the rule using `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT` and then list the rules using `iptables -S`, iptables is giving `-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT`.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently installed CentOS 6.5 as a virtual machine for the same reason, to use as a virtual web server. Anyway, I followed [this very detailed how-to from the CentOS wiki](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Network/IPTables). Then, as per the answer of @slm, I added port 80 to it and saved using `sudo /etc/init.d/iptables save`.

`iptables -L -v` has this output:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     any     anywhere             anywhere            
  214 17168 ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
    1    44 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ssh 
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:http 

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 169 packets, 15164 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Answer (score 0):

If want to edit your firewall settings but you're not familiar with `iptables`, I suggest you to use the `system-config-firewall-tui` tool if you have not an X server, of use the `system-config-firewall`, which is the GUI tool for it.